# Create list with expandable element - Android

Tags: android, list, listview

I would like to create a list of elements that can be expandable and looks like the Google Clock app

[image]

Which Android element should I use ?

Thanks a lot by advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use recyclerview.The google clock app is using recyclerview.